# jQuery slow reveal on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a slow reveal on a particular div with an id of 'contentblock' on page load.  This is my first time trying to code something in jQuery and I continue to fail. The following is my latest attempt, but I'm a complete newbie to this and surprisingly google hasn't been a whole lot of help.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).onload(function(){
   $('#contentblock').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
 });


</script>
```

before that I also had the following instead of the window onload line above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

But that didn't have any success either.  Can someone help a jQuery newbie out?

Comment: Tip: return false; -- you only need to return a value if the calling function is expecting one. Otherwise, leave this out.

Comment: Post an example on jsfiddle.net and post the URL here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll need to make sure the element is hidden (or it won't be shown, since it's already visible). You can do this in either CSS or JavaScript/jQuery:

```
#contentblock {
    display: none;
}
```

Or:

```
$('#contentblock').hide();
```

If you use CSS to hide the element you need to be aware that the element will remain hidden in the event of JavaScript being disabled in the user's browser. If you use JavaScript there's the problem that the element will likely flicker as it's first shown and then hidden.

And then call:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#contentblock').slideDown('slow');
 });
```

I've made two amendments to your jQuery, first I've changed `onload` to `load` and I've also removed the `return false`, since the `load()` method doesn't expect any value to be returned it serves no purpose herein.

For the above jQuery you can use instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contentblock').slideDown('slow');
 });
```

Comment: Hmm, that did work and thank you for the detailed explanation. However, for some reason the div starts off at about 50% already revealed and then finishes revealing to 100%.  Any idea why? I'm using css to hide the div.

Comment: Hmm, the problem seems to be with my css of min-height: 400px;  Its starting at the 400px and then revealing.  Any way to override that?

Comment: The `.slideDown` method is just animating the `height` property of the element, so the `min-height` CSS will always apply during the animation. You could set it to zero before you start animating (use `.css('min-height','0px')` ), and set it back at the end of the animation (the `.slideDown` method takes a function that will execute when the animation completes).

Comment: Yep; get rid of the `min-height`. Or add a new class to the element as a call-back to the `slideDown()` method. Or use `animate()` instead to animate to that height.

Comment: I tried the following which seems logical but it still starts off at 400px and then seems to go larger.
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contentblock').hide();
   $('#contentblock').css('min-height','0px');
   $('#contentblock').delay(200).slideDown(2000);
   $('#contentblock').css('min-height','400px');
 });
(Removing the min-height altogether works of course, but I need it for certain pages I'm including).

Comment: In case anyone else needs it.  I was able to get it with the following: 

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contentblock').hide();
   $('#contentblock').css('min-height','0px');
   $('#contentblock').delay(200).slideDown(2000, function() {
   $('#contentblock').css('min-height','400px') 
  });
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('#contentblock').is(':hidden'))
  {
    $('#contentblock').slideDown('slow');
  }
});
```

if you have jquery added to your project and your div is display none ... something like this should work.